# List element is only picking up last element and printing in excel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My code is to print a list of error messsages from a web page in to excel using webelement list, but it is only printing one the last message in to excel. please help. I am using below code.

```
public void printoutput(int sheetnum, int row, int col, String str) throws IOException
{

wb.getSheetAt(sheetnum).getRow(row).createCell(col).setCellValue(str);
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("/Users/paulami/Desktop/AP_Portal/TestData.xlsx");//to write in excel
wb.write(fos);
//wb.close();
}
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://TestLink");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(5000);


        {

            errorMessage = element.getText();
            System.out.println(errorMessage);
            excel.printoutput(1, row, 22, errorMessage);

        }
   List<WebElement> allelements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-meui-cor']/ul/li"));
    System.out.println(allelements);
    String errorMessage="";
for(WebElement element : allelements)

        {

            errorMessage = element.getText();
            System.out.println(errorMessage);
            excel.printoutput(1, row, 22, errorMessage);

        }
```

Comment: What does `System.out.println(allelements.size());` print?

Comment: @DarshanMehta I think it will show the number of messages the List contains. In my case it's 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's writing only last value because of the following line:

```
excel.printoutput(1, row, 22, errorMessage);
```

I don't know what the arguments are for `printoutput` method, but presumably one of them is `cell` number. The above line keeps writing different messages to the same cell and hence, previous value always gets overwritten, resuting in only the last value getting printed. The updated solution should look like this (pseudo code):

```
for(WebElement element : allelements){
    excel.printoutput(1, row++, 22, element.getText());
}
```

Or, if you want to append the content, you first need to retrieve the content and append `element.getText()` to it.

**Update**

To write all the messages into one cell, you first need to create a `String` which contains let's say a comma separated values and write it to `excel`, e.g.:

```
String content = allelements.stream().map(e -> e.getText()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
excel.printoutput(1, row, 22, content);
```

This will write all the messages to a single row. You can then repeat the same approach with different row number to write new set of messages.

Comment: excel.printoutput(1, row, 22, errorMessage) @Darshan Mehta, the arguments are sheetnum, row, column and obvious errormessage.I want these messages to be written in the column of same row.

Comment: So, you need to increment row number every time, to write messages to different row otherwise it will overwrite the previous message. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Actually, lets say for the first itereation, I want to capture 6 messages, ALL of which I want to write in the number 22 column of 1st row. In next iteration, lets say it will capture 4 messages, and I want to write all 4 in the 22nd column

Comment: Thank you so much Darshan!! it worked. INstead of ",", I just put a "\n" since my requirement is like that.

Comment: Sorry to open this thread again. I have tried several ways, but stuck. For invalid input, it is capturing the error messages and writing in excel. When I am running the same code for valid inputs, for which there is no error, it is still retaining those old error messages whereas, my intention is to overwrite that cell with blank value. Please help if you can. @Darshan Mehta

Comment: I guess you are not clearing out the previous messages. Maybe try `list.clear()` or `list = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: I tried with allelements.clear(), but did not work. :(

Comment: Okay, are you trying to write the list to the same cell as previous? Also, does it append the list to cell content while writing?

Comment: For invalid input, it is capturing the error messages and lets say writing in column 22. When I am running the same code for valid inputs, for which there is no error, it is still retaining those old error messages whereas, my intention is to overwrite that same cell (column 22) with blank because this time there is no element in the List. Does it make sense? let me know if you need anymore information. Thanks for you time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I am still beginning in java , but just will like to  propose something, just check and see: check if the number of elements in your list is greater than 1
If it is smaller than "one" that means your function "findelements()" has something wrong ---- allelements.size();

Comment: The number of elements are 6, And I just checked by using allelements.size, it is showing 6 only.